# How to dynamically deploy event-triggered (or database-triggered) Apache Beam pipelines to Dataflow using JavaSDK?

Tags: java, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

Currently I have a working pipeline and I want to dynamically deploy Beam pipelines to Dataflow. For example, one pipeline is running on Dataflow and when there is a new database record coming in (event/database triggered), the same pipeline will be automatically run without affecting the other one. One solution is to use Dataflow template, however, it doesn't support KafkaIO. Is there any direction that I can go for?

Comment: Is your description only an example? I am asking because it makes less sense to have a new pipeline for a single record.

Comment: @RuiWang Sorry if I have been unclear. IT is not a new pipeline. It is the same pipeline. When a new record comes in, it will be triggered to run.